# Привет. Ошибка в массиве или цикле for

Tags: c#

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int i,j;
    int[,] mas = { { 100 }, { 100 } };
    Console.Write("Введите n: ");
    int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.Write("Введите m: ");
    int m = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    for(i =1; i <= m * n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 1; j <= m*n; j++)
        {
            mas[i, j] = i + j;
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        for (i = 1; i <= m*n; i++)
        {
            for (j = 1; j <= m*n; j++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(mas[i, j] + " ");
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine();

    }
}
```

По идее, должен выводиться массив, который состоит из n строк и m столбцов, а каждый элемент таблицы равнялся сумме номера строки и номера столбца. Но, 1) почему-то не выводится ничего вовсе; 2) даже при каких-то корректировках с моей стороны решение неверное.
Надеюсь на Вашу помощь.

Comment: какие n и m ты пробуешь?

Comment: m и n должны вводиться с клавиатуры. Я пробовал совершенно разные значение ( 1,1; 2,3; 3,1 и другие).

Comment: Вы зря одни и те же переменные используете в разных вложенных в друг друга циклах. Во внутреннем цикле если `i` увеличится, то внешний цикл по `i` тоже закончится - ведь условие выхода из цикла выполнится. Таким образом, внешний цикл по `i` выполнится только один раз.

Comment: Так что переменные цикла лучше описывать в самой конструкции цикла: `for(var i = 1; i <= m * n; i++)`, и тогда компилятор вам не даст уже такую ошибку совершить, на внутренние циклы с таким же названием переменной он будет ругаться, что переменная уже определена и вы сразу поймёте в чём ошибка. Или вы намеренно вынесли описание переменных в начало программы, чтобы избежать ошибок компиляции? Вот очень зря, если так.

Comment: Странно, ошибка  "Index was outside the bounds of the array." ("Индекс находится за пределами массива".)

Comment: Собственно да, вы ещё и массив неправильно инициализируете, он у вас мелкий совсем получается - из двух элементов. Так что вылетает ещё до того как до логической ошибки с повторением названий переменных доходит.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проще привести сразу правильный код:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.Write("Введите n: ");
    int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.Write("Введите m: ");
    int m = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    int[,] mas = new int[m, n];
    for(var i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        for (var j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            mas[i, j] = i + j;
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        for (var j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            Console.Write(mas[i, j] + " ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Ваши ошибки:

- Инициализировать массив нужно того размера, который вам задан через ввод. Вы же инициализируете массив просто двумя значениями, у вас получается массив размером 1x2, в него нельзя записать произвольное число значений, больше этой размерности
- Индексация массивов начинается с `0`, а не с `1` и заканчивается `n-1` и `m-1` индексами
- Переменные циклов `for` лучше описывать в самой конструкции цикла (см. мои комментарии к вашему вопросу)
- Вторые два цикла должны выполняться **после** завершения первых двух циклов, а не внутри них